# build.shibboleth.net gives wrong certificate for some regions

Tags: ssl, dns, openssl, ssl-certificate, shibboleth

One of our Jenkins builds is failing trying to connect to `build.shibboleth.net`. So I did some analysis.

Please look at these openssl results from 2 regions.

In South Asia region: It gives the cert of `test.shibboleth.net`, which is wrong.

```
$ openssl s_client -host build.shibboleth.net -port 443 -prexit -showcerts

CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 C = US, ST = Ohio, O = Shibboleth Consortium, CN = Shibboleth Project Intermediate CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Ohio/O=Shibboleth Consortium/CN=test.shibboleth.net
   i:/C=US/ST=Ohio/O=Shibboleth Consortium/CN=Shibboleth Project Intermediate CA
...
...
```

In USA region: It gives the cert of `shibboleth.net`, which is correct.

```
$ openssl s_client -host build.shibboleth.net -port 443 -prexit -showcerts

CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = shibboleth.net
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = shibboleth.net
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
...
...
```

And `resolveip build.shibboleth.net` gives `3.213.250.186` from both regions.

Why is it giving a wrong certificate for one region? I have no clue how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd speculate that the results above aren't caused by region dependence but instead that you're using a different version of `openssl` on the two client machines.

We used to run the different vhosts on different IP addresses. Now, one address is used for everything and we rely on [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to distinguish requests so that the right certificate is returned.

If the `openssl` client doesn't present the server name then you might get a default certificate instead of the one you expected. Whether `openssl` does that or not depends on the version of `openssl` in use (`openssl version` 1.1.1 does, earlier versions don't).

You can try adding `-servername build.shibboleth.net` to your `openssl` command to see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: You're spot on. It's SNI. Now the question is why maven is not sending it automatically. Did a google search and it seems I might have to upgrade maven. I'll give it a try. Thank you.